# Finding a set of nodes in an XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xpath

I know this question will be a repetition of other questions but I am trying this for around 2 days now and hasn't got the luck. Kindly do not get offended with the repeated question and respond.

I have the following XML:

```
<SurveyForm xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXXXSerives.Classes.Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sections>
<section>
<fields>
<formfield>
<fieldname>Lessee</fieldname>
<fieldtype>textfield</fieldtype>
<isdisabled>True</isdisabled>
<isrequired>False</isrequired>
<pkformfieldid>8</pkformfieldid>
<placeholder>Lessee</placeholder>
<validation/>
</formfield>
<formfield>
<fieldname>Remarks</fieldname>
<fieldtype>textarea</fieldtype>
<isdisabled>False</isdisabled>
<isrequired>False</isrequired>
<pkformfieldid>26</pkformfieldid>
<placeholder/>
<validation/>
</formfield>
<formfield>
<fieldname>Body &amp; Exterior</fieldname>
<fieldtype>combo</fieldtype>
<isdisabled>False</isdisabled>
<isrequired>False</isrequired>
<pkformfieldid>19</pkformfieldid>
<placeholder>Good, Average, Bad</placeholder>
<validation/>
</formfield>
<formfield>
<fieldname>Vehicle Type</fieldname>
<fieldtype>combo</fieldtype>
<isdisabled>False</isdisabled>
<isrequired>False</isrequired>
<pkformfieldid>12</pkformfieldid>
<placeholder>Coupe, Hybrid, Sports</placeholder>
<validation/>
</formfield>
.
.
.
.
</fields>
<sectionid>1</sectionid>
<sectionname>Inspection Survey</sectionname>
</section>
<section>
<fields>
<formfield>
<fieldname>Last Name</fieldname>
<fieldtype>textfield</fieldtype>
<isdisabled>False</isdisabled>
<isrequired>True</isrequired>
<pkformfieldid>2</pkformfieldid>
<placeholder>Last Name</placeholder>
<validation/>
</formfield>
</fields>
<sectionid>2</sectionid>
<sectionname>Suspicious Section</sectionname>
</section>
<section>
<fields/>
<sectionid>3</sectionid>
<sectionname>Bikes Inspections</sectionname>
</section>
</sections>
</SurveyForm>
```

I need to first extract all the `<formfield>` nodes, which are under each `<section>` node.

What I tried so far:

```
XmlDocument DocumentForParsing = new XmlDocument();
DocumentForParsing.LoadXml(submittedForm);

if (rootNode.InnerXml.Contains("section"))
{
     XmlNode SectionNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("..//section");
     if (SectionNode.InnerXml.Contains("formfield"))
         fieldNodes = SectionNode.SelectNodes(".//formfield");
     foreach (XmlElement fieldNode in fieldNodes)
         {
          .
          .
          .
         }
}
```

Later I tried to use LINQ, and after many tries this is the latest I tried to use:

```
XElement rootNode = XElement.Parse(DocumentForParsing.InnerXml);
        var formfields = rootNode.Element("sections").Element("section")
            .Element("fields").Elements("formfield").Select(field => field);

foreach (var fields in formfields)
{
    string a = fields.Element("fieldname").Value;
    string b = fields.Element("fieldtype").Value;
    string c = fields.Element("placeholder").Value;
}
```

But in both cases I get `null` at the sections part. I have tried different combinations of XPath as well. But no luck.
**Note:**
I am getting the XML in a string from the MySQL database. While debugging I can find the whole document. But I cannot get to the Section and Formfield part. Please help, thank you all.

Comment: You're not looking for elements in the right namespace, basically. I'd definitely stick with the LINQ to XML approach. I'll try to find a duplicate now...

Comment: That `InnerXml` part looks very suspicious, are you sure it's what you want (i.e. it might return text instead of a data structure)? Second, I think you need to search for `sections`(notice the `s`) first, since your `<section>`s are children of `<sections>`.

Comment: I have also tried removing namespace manually from the DB field. But still could not resolve it. I am trying the duplicate you advised.

Comment: @EmilLundberg Kindly paste the code step by step, I will try it and tell you. I have been trying different combinations from yesterday morning. I cannot paste all that I have tried here, obviously.

Comment: I don't have any code to paste, as I'm lazily browsing SO on my phone.